# How to view enabled apis for a project in google developer's console?

Tags: android, developer-console

It seems there was the option years before, but now I don't find it. link: [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com)

Comment: ON Dashboard at bottom there is one table which displays the currently enabled API on your project

Comment: @RohitSuthar Hmm! I did see them before, but the indications whether those are the apis enabled for my project are a bit unconvincing. Besides what makes it even more confusing is that there are whole lot of other apis included which I didn't enable myself. These should be just some simple UI choices that those brilliant minds up there decide otherwise.